# Android Bluetooth beacon unique identifier

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, altbeacon

[Here](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html) is the library that shows how to use it to transmission and reception. I use the following for transmission

```
Beacon beacon = new Beacon.Builder()
    .setId1("2f234454-cf6d-4a0f-adf2-f4911ba9ffa6")
    .setId2("1")
    .setId3("2")
    .setManufacturer(0x0118)
    .setTxPower(-59)
    .setDataFields(Arrays.asList(new Long[] {0l}))
    .build();
BeaconParser beaconParser = new BeaconParser()
    .setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25");

BeaconTransmitter beaconTransmitter = new BeaconTransmitter(getApplicationContext(), beaconParser);
beaconTransmitter.startAdvertising(beacon);
```

which works successfully for me and I can see it from another opensource app as well.

In receiving, I use BeaconConsumer interface and onBeaconServiceConnect is successfully called as I can see in the log, but I have a problem with the Region function as shown in the web example or below

```
 beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myRangingUniqueId", null, null, null));
```

What is "myRangingUniqueId" since the following three-part are id1, id2, id3 respectively for transmitting, so what is this parameter?

My understanding is that this Region function will filter out certain id, which matches given parameters, and for Bluetooth altbeacon UUID is composed by the three-parts id1, id2, id3. Hence what is "myRangingUniqueId" really confused me. According to my experiment, this parameter is not the same as UUID since I set it to target UUID doesn't work.

I cannot explain what the is "myRangingUniqueId".

Please correct me, if I am wrong.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The string identifier of a Region is used as a key to identify the region for start and stop purposes.

EXAMPLE:

```
Region region1 = Region("abc123", null, null, null));
beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region1);
```

The above code starts ranging for all beacons regardless of identifiers.

If you then run this code:

```
Region region2 = Region("abc123", Identifier.parse("2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6"), null, null));
beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region1);
```

This will **stop ranging** for the first region shown above and  replace it with a new region that  only matches beacons with the first identifier shown.  The first parameter matching is what triggers this behavior.

If you wanted both regions to be ranged at the same time you could do this:

```
Region region1 = Region("abc123", null, null, null));
beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region1);

Region region2 = Region("def456", Identifier.parse("2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6")
beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region2);
```

Because both regions have a different key, they can be used simultaneously.

The same key matching process is used when you call `stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(region)`

The APIs work this way because they are designed to be similar to iOS CoreLocation APIs for interoperability. On iOS, the APIs use the same technique.   This makes it easy to build cross-platform apps.